# How to get to a debugger in ejs with express?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I appear to have a bug inside some ejs code that's getting served up by express. I generally use the excellent node-inspector package to debug in express and node.js. But it doesn't seem to be available in ejs. Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

In your route:

```
res.locals.inspect = inspect;
```

Then in your view:

```
<%= inspect(data) %>
```